# Duplicate check on mobile phone number field on Sugar CRM lead imports

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have a CSV file with set of records on it. While I use this CSV file to import leads into database it has a feature to check for duplicates. But unfortunately I could not apply the duplicate check on `mobile phone` field. Is there any way to configure that so that I can check for duplicates on `mobile phone` field as well. I am using Sugar CE 6.4 build. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find whole your answers in this very good Developer Blog Post : http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/11/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-sugar-6-3-import-duplicate-fields-checking/